# What does a she-wolf mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This is strikingly similar to the story of Ashina, the founder of the Goturks, whose mother also was a she-wolf.

What does "she-wolf" mean in this context? I have looked up in dictionaries, but it is still unclear to me. Some dictionaries define it as "a predatory woman", but I still can't understand the meaning of "predatory". Does it mean a woman who exploits others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means a [female wolf](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/she-wolf).

[image: image of a wolf]

This passage seems to be about a [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashina_tribe#Legends), where that kind of thing can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, a "she wolf" simply means a female wolf.

In a fantasy story it can refer to a female werewolf.

Figuratively, it can mean a woman who the writer sees as being LIKE a wolf, that is, fierce and aggressive.

Or "predatory". "Predatory" means a creature that tracks down and kills other creatures. Among wild animals, normally we'd expect for food. "Predatory" can refer to people who exploit others. Like someone who molests children is often called a "predator".